# Migrating from MSAccessDB to SQLLite

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, database-migration

I have a application written long time back using the MS Access as the configuration database. It was using OLEDB Provider (Jet Engine) for retrieving data from the configuration DB.
I intended to replace MS Access Db lightweight RDBMS which requires no additional installation requirements. Thinking of using SQLLite which seems to suite my needs. Wanted to check if anyone have invovled in migrating the data from MSAccess to SQL Lite. Is there an easy way to migrate the schema and data?

Comment: No. SqLite is quite limited compared to Access, so there will be no direct conversion.

Comment: ... although if all you want to do is copy the tables (and their data) into SQLite then you could probably just install the SQLite ODBC driver on the machine where the Access is installed and then use Access' "Export" feature to push the tables to a SQLite database.

Answer (score 2):

You can quite much transfer data and schema if you setup the ODBC driver for sqlite.

Once done then you can run append queries in Access to export to the sqlite database.

Of course with sqlite you don't get or have forms, reports or a coding language. So, you have to replace that part of Access with some other kind of development platform.

So, you need to get a ODBC driver for sqlite.
This one works well:
http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

So, once you done the above, then you can link from access to sql lite. You can even edit data with Access forms, or even run access reports against data in sqlite.